# Magento 2.4.3 Login not returned to same page after login

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.3

After searching all day I can't seem to find a solution to this issue, so hoping someone can assist. When customer log's in via the login page they are always returned to the customer dashboard instead of the page they logged in from. I've set the correct option in admin available at

**configuration>customers>customer configuration>login options>Redirect Customer to Account Dashboard after Logging in** to '**NO**'

refreshed cache, rerun all commands but whatever I try it always seems to return to dashboard. I've removed all 3rd party extensions to test but still goes to /customer/account/index/ page instead of original page. Any suggestions?

when the login link from the header is click it does correctly append the referer tag (as below) but it  wont return to the correct page.

**/customer/account/login/referer/aHR0cHM6Ly90ZXN0LnNwZWVkY3JldGUuY28udWsvY3VzdG9tZXIvYWNjb3VudC9pbmRleC8%2C/**

Comment: Not an answer! Can't comment without 50 Reputation so I have to use the site WRONG to ask my question. Have you found a solution to this? I see you asked this 2 months ago, I am also experiencing this same issue. For after adding a custom route for wishlist the redirect stops working that would normally load the customers wishlist after the login when they clicked add to wishlist on a product page.

Comment: No. Still no further forward